# JavaFX shapes not showing up?

Tags: java, javafx, java.util.scanner

I need to create an image using instructions from a text file. I have almost finished, but 2 of my shapes are not showing up. https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKxwK.jpg The top pic is what I have, and the bottom is what I need. As you can see, one of the circles in the top right is not showing and the rectangle building the base of the rocket isn't either. this is the relevant code:

```
Group root = new Group();  //creates group for all shapes to go in
        try {
            Scanner obj = new Scanner(new File("scene.txt"));  //reads text file
            boolean shouldBreak = false;
            while(obj.hasNextLine()){
                String[] strArray = obj.nextLine().split(" ");  //splits all commands to new line

                switch(strArray[0]){
                    case "SIZE":                                      //sets size of window
                        fwidth = Double.parseDouble(strArray[1]);
                        fheight = Double.parseDouble(strArray[2]);
                        break;

                        case "LINE":                                      //creates each line
                        la = Double.parseDouble(strArray[1]);
                        lb = Double.parseDouble(strArray[2]);
                        lc = Double.parseDouble(strArray[3]);
                        ld = Double.parseDouble(strArray[4]);
                        Line line = new Line(la,lb,lc,ld);
                        line.setStyle("-fx-stroke:rgb(127,244,16)");
                        root.getChildren().add(line);
                        break;

                        case "CIRCLE":                                    //creates each circle
                        cx = Double.parseDouble(strArray[1]);
                        cy = Double.parseDouble(strArray[2]);
                        cr = Double.parseDouble(strArray[3]);
                        Circle circle = new Circle(cx,cy,cr);
                        circle.setFill(null);
                        circle.setStyle("-fx-stroke:rgb(127,244,16)");
                        root.getChildren().add(circle);
                        break;

                        case "RECTANGLE":                                 //creates each rectangle
                        rx = Double.parseDouble(strArray[1]);
                        ry = Double.parseDouble(strArray[2]);
                        rw = Double.parseDouble(strArray[3]);
                        rh = Double.parseDouble(strArray[4]);
                        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(rx,ry,rw,rh);
                        rect.setFill(null);
                        rect.setStyle("-fx-stroke:rgb(127,244,16)");
                        root.getChildren().add(rect);
                        break;

                        case "TEXT":                                      //creates each string of text
                        tx = Double.parseDouble(strArray[1]);
                        ty = Double.parseDouble(strArray[2]);
                        for(int i = 3; i < strArray.length; i++){
                            ts = ts + " " + strArray[i];
                        }
                        Text text = new Text(tx,ty,ts);
                        text.setStyle("-fx-stroke:rgb(127,244,16)");
                        root.getChildren().add(text);
                        ts = "";
                        break;

                        case "//":                                        //ignores comments
                        obj.nextLine();
                        break;

                        case "END":                                       //stops reading file
                        shouldBreak = true;
                        break;
                }
                if(shouldBreak){break;}
            }

            Scene scene = new Scene(root, fwidth, fheight, Color.BLACK);
            stage.setTitle("graphic");
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.show();
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException fileNotFoundException) {
            fileNotFoundException.printStackTrace();
        }
        }

        /**
         * The main method
         * @param args
         */

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            launch(args);
        }
    }
```

i've looked online and can't find anything about it. if anyone knows why just 2 of the shapes aren't appearing, any help is appreciated.

Comment: don't repost questions ..

Comment: ... instead edit the first and clarify why its answer doesn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
                    case "//":            //ignores comments
                    obj.nextLine();
                    break;
```

You are causing it to skip an additional instruction line here. I'm assuming this is whats making you skip certain shapes. Below is what it should be.

```
                    case "//":            //ignores comments
                    break;
```